# Pythonで開いたファイルの種別を判断したい

Tags: python, python3

**質問内容**
ファイルを開いた後に、種別を判断したいのですが、スマートな方法はないでしょうか？

**やりたいこと**
とあるデータをバイナリ形式とテキスト形式のどちらでも受け付けるようにしたいです。
例えば、"F0FFFFFF000102"といったデータをバイナリ形式でもテキスト形式でも読み取りたい場合、以下のようなコードでファイルを開きます。

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/" ,title = "Select file",filetypes = (("binary files","*.bin"),("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
fp = open(path,'rb')
data = fp.read()
```

テキスト形式の場合、dataの中身は、

```
data: b'f0ffffff000102
```

バイナリ形式の場合、dataの中身は、

```
data: b'\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01\x02
```

そこで、文字列に変換して、'\x'を取り除けば、どちらの形式でも同じデータになると考えました。

```
sdata = data.decode()
data = sdata.strip('\x')
```

しかし、バイナリ形式では、data.decode()の時点で、uft-8ではないため、エラーが発生します。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

**使用している環境**
OS: Windows10 Pro
IDE: VisualStudioCode バージョン: 1.36.1 (user setup)

Comment: バイナリ形式のデータを16進表記文字列に変換するのは `data.hex()` とすると良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
hex()でテキスト形式を処理すると全てASCIIコードになってしまいます。今回はファイルのヘッダ部分が固定値なのでこれで判定できるとは思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルタイプを判別する方法が別にありました。以下リンク先を参照してください。

[How to know the filetype through python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743548/how-to-know-the-filetype-through-python)

具体的には以下のコードで十分です。日本語名のファイルも読み込めました。

```
import mimetypes

ret = mimetypes.guess_type(path, strict=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの種別を判断するためのlibmagicというライブラリがあります。
[libmagic(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html)

このlibmagicのPythonラッパーがいくつか存在するので、これを利用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

## python-magic

[ahupp/python-magic: A python wrapper for libmagic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

> ```py
> >>> import magic
> >>> magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf")
> 'PDF document, version 1.2'
> >>> magic.from_buffer(open("testdata/test.pdf").read(1024))
> 'PDF document, version 1.2'
> >>> magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf", mime=True)
> 'application/pdf'
> ```
>
> [python-magic/README.md at master · ahupp/python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/8753c3cf284c1b83eaf0dd0f520400ec7652ee81/README.md)

## python-libmagic

[python-libmagic · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-libmagic/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
しかしながら、わたくしの環境では、pipコマンドが正常に動作しないようで、新たな問題となってしまっています。

Comment: pipについてはC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Lib\site-packagesにパスを通して解決しました。
その結果、import magicにより、ファイルの判別ができるようになりました。ただし、Windowsではサイトにも説明があるようにDLLのインストールが必要のようです。

Comment: 日本語のファイル名に対応できないことが分かりました。残念です。